# The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Contacts>\n .Where(c => __res_RelatedContacts_0\n.Any(r => r.IdVal.Equals(c.ContactId)))' could not be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am using asp.net core 3.1 and EFCore 3.1.1.

Code :

```
public class SampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Articles> Articles
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var converter = new NumberToStringConverter<int>();
        // For Articles
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().OwnsMany(p => p.RelatedCountries, a =>
        {
            a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("Articlesid");
            a.Property<int>("id");
            a.Property(o => o.IdVal);
        }

        );
    }
}

public class Articles
{
    public int ArticleId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ICollection<RelatedEntityId> RelatedContacts
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class RelatedEntityId
{
    public int IdVal
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

My Service class :

```
public class ArticleService : IArticleService
{
    private readonly SampleDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly ICacheService<Images, ImageDTO> _imageCacheService;
    private readonly ICacheService<Countries, CountryDTO> _countryCacheService;
    private readonly ICommonService _commonService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public ArticleService(SampleDbContext dbContext, ICacheService<Images, ImageDTO> imageCacheService, ICacheService<Countries, CountryDTO> countryCacheService, ICommonService commonService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
        _imageCacheService = imageCacheService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(imageCacheService));
        _countryCacheService = countryCacheService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(countryCacheService));
        _commonService = commonService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(commonService));
        _mapper = mapper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapper));
    }

    public async Task<ArticleDTO> GetArticleDetailsAsync(int articleId, int defaultLanguageId, List<int> localeLanguageIdList)
    {
        // Get articles
        var articles = await _dbContext.Articles.Where(a => a.ArticleId.Equals(articleId) && a.IsPublished.Equals(true)).OrderByDescending(a => a.ArticleId).Select(a => new
        {
        a.ArticleId, a.PublishedDate, a.Author, a.ImageId, a.State, a.Type, a.SubType, a.ResourcePosition, a.DisclaimerId, a.CreatedDate, a.UpdatedDate, a.NotificationSentDate, a.Title, a.TeaserText, a.Content, a.RelatedContacts, a.LanguageId
        }

        ).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        var res = articles.Where(a => a.LanguageId.Equals(defaultLanguageId) && Convert.ToDateTime(a.PublishedDate) <= DateTime.UtcNow).FirstOrDefault();
        var contacts = new List<ContactDTO>();
        if (res.RelatedContacts.Count > 0)
        {
            contacts = await _dbContext.Contacts.Where(co => res.RelatedContacts.Any(r => r.IdVal.Equals(co.ContactId))).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message:

> "message": "GraphQL.ExecutionError: The LINQ expression 'DbSet\n    .Where(c => __res_RelatedContacts_0\n        .Any(r => r.IdVal.Equals(c.ContactId)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.\n ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet\n    .Where(c => __res_RelatedContacts_0\n        .Any(r => r.IdVal.Equals(c.ContactId)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.g__CheckTranslated|8_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass8_0& )\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Author.Query.Persistence.ArticleService.GetArticleDetailsAsync(Int32 articleId, Int32 defaultLanguageId, List`1 localeLanguageIdList) in /src/QueryStack/Author.Query.Persistence/ArticleService.cs:line 88\n   at Author.Query.Persistence.ArticleService.GetArticleAsync(Int32 articleId, String countryName) in /src/QueryStack/Author.Query.Persistence/ArticleService.cs:line 47\n   at GraphQL.DataLoader.DataLoaderBase`1.DispatchAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Author.Query.New.API.GraphQL.Resolvers.ArticlesResolver.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<b__2>d.MoveNext() in /src/QueryStack/Author.Query.New.API/GraphQL/Resolvers/ArticlesResolver.cs:line 41\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at GraphQL.Types.ResolveFieldContext`1.TryAsyncResolve[TResult](Func`2 resolve, Func`2 error)\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---"

Can anyone help me to know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please pay attention to formatting to make it easier to read the question (esp. the error message).

Comment: The error is clear. The LINQ query you used can't be translated to SQL. Where's the query in all this?

Comment: The problem looks to be `co => res.RelatedContacts.Any(` ? There's no way a C#-side lookup like `res.RelatedContacts.Any` can be translated to SQL - the data isn't in the database for one thing. If you wanted to generate a `co.ContactId IN (1,4,78,...)` clause you need to put the values in an array or list and use `thatArray.Contains(co.ContactId)`. EF Core will generate the `IN` clause values from the contents of that array. A *better* option though would be to rewrite all the code and queries in a way that doesn't load everything in memory.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Load contacts with an article published in a specific language? Doesn't the `Contact` class have an `Articles` property?